# StringBuffer or HashMap for appending codes?

Tags: java

**StringBuffer or HashMap**

Which is the best way to append codes and also makes performance better.

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
DBDatabase db = UTIL.getDatabase();
sql.append("SELECT I.FLDCODE, I.FLDDESCR, I.FLDWORKPHON FROM ");
sql.append(db.getSchema());
sql.append("TRNINSTR I, ");
sql.append(db.getSchema());
sql.append("TRNCRSIN C WHERE C.FLDCOURSE = ? AND C.FLDINSTRUCT = I.FLDCODE AND (I.FLDINACTIVE IS NULL OR I.FLDINACTIVE <> 'y') ORDER BY C.FLDSEQUENCE");
DBPreparedStatement stmt = new DBPreparedStatement(db, sql, "TrainPage.getInfoInstrList");
stmt.setString(1, courseType);
DBResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
stmt.close();
```

Comment: How do you want to use hashmap to append codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear ("appending codes"? "HashMap"?), but I'll assume that you are asking what is the more efficient way to build a String.

In general, a StringBuilder is more efficient than a StringBuffer, because the latter's methods are synchronized and this is just an unnecessary overhead for a thread-confined object.

But then there is the question of whether using a StringBuilder is more efficient than simple String concatenation.  And the answer to that is that "it depends".

If you are doing lots of separate concatenations, then a StringBuilder is typically faster; e.g.

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    s += "X";
}
```

If you are doing all of the concatenations in one expression, then it probably makes no difference:

```
String s = "Hi " + name + ". It is a might fine " + day + ".";
```

This is because the Java compiler will turn that into code that creates a StringBuilder and performs a series of `append` calls.

However, that is a slight over-simplification.  On the one hand, if your application can easily calculate the length of the final String, you can get somewhat better performance using a StringBuilder by allocating the builder with the right initial capacity.  On the other hand, the compiler will evaluate concatenations of String literals before hand, so

```
String s = "Hi " + "mom" + ".  is a might fine " + "tuesday" + ".";
```

will be faster than:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Hi ");
sb.append("mom");
sb.append(".  is a might fine ");
sb.append("tuesday");
sb.append(".");
String s = sb.toString();
```

But the bottom line is that **it probably doesn't matter**.  Unless you do a huge amount of string building, the chances are that the impact on the overall performance of your application will be minimal.

Answer (score 6):

[StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) performs even better. Bear in mind that the slow part is database access not statement preparation.